# Delay between Java splash screen and application screen loading

Tags: java, jnlp, javafx-2

I have a JavaFx 2.0 desktop application that I intend to run via the JWS using a jnlp file. 
The problem I'm facing is that it takes a significant amount of time between the java default splash screen disappearing and my application loading. In the meantime, the user is left guessing as to what is happening. Is there a way, I can make this loading process more user-friendly and display/inform about what is happening before my application actually gets displayed? I've tried using a preloader, as described in the JavaFx deployment article: http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/deployment/preloaders.htm#BABCDIHD, but that does not seem to do the trick either. Here's how my JNLP file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jnlp spec="1.0+"  xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" codebase="file:///C%3A/Program%20Files/HP/Pulse/PulseLite"href="iMonLauncher.jnlp">    
    <information>   
        <title>iMonLauncher</title>  
        <vendor>Administrator</vendor>  
        <homepage href="file:///C%3A/Program%20Files/HP/Pulse/PulseLite"/>  
        <description>iMonLauncher</description> 
        <offline-allowed/>   
        </information>     
        <security>       
        <all-permissions/> 
    </security>
     <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
        <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.0+"  
        href="http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/javafx/javafx-windows-i586__Vlatest.exe "/>
     </resources>
     <resources os="Windows" arch="x64">
        <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.0+" href="http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/javafx/javafx-windows-x64__Vlatest.exe "/>
      </resources> 
    <resources> 
        <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>  
        <jar href="iMon.jar" size="593908"/>            
        <jar href="lib/iMonPreloader.jar" size="4004" download="progress" />            
        <jar href="lib/ibase-core.jar" size="200674"/>    
        <jar href="lib/ibase-fx.jar" size="190545"/>      
        <jar href="lib/imonDB.jar" main="true" size="141462"/>    

    </resources>      
    <application-desc name="iMon" main-class="imon.Main" >   </application-desc>    
    <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="imon.Main"  name="iMon"  
                        preloader-class="imon.MyPreloader"/><update check="background"/>    
</jnlp>
```

Thanks in advance for all the suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you perform any complex operations before stage.show() in you Application class?

Try to drop then and see if there would be any delay still. If that was the reason you may want to adjust design of your application to perform complex initialization after show() call while presenting user some loading bar at that time.